# In mutt, <End> and <Home> do not work

Tags: mutt

I had a very old (10+ years) Debian system, which I recently updated to the latest one. Everything works fine (or I already fixed the problems), except one thing.

In mutt, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> stopped working. If I press any of them, I get:

```
Key is not bound.  Press '?' for help.
```

I tried to add:

```
bind  generic,index <Home> first-entry
bind  generic,index <End> last-entry
```

and t did not help.

Also, I tried to add:

```
bind  generic,index ^[[H first-entry
bind  generic,index ^[[F last-entry
```

and it did not help either.

When I add:

```
bind  generic,index 0 first-entry
bind  generic,index $ last-entry
```

though, it works. So I suppose that the problem is only
with the two (or some more) particular keys.

Any ideas what I could fix/check?

**Update**

If I press <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>home</kbd>, I get `^[[H`,
if I press <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>home</kbd>, I get `^[[F`.

If I run

```
:exec what-key
```

for <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd> I get

```
Char = H, Octal = 110, Decimal = 72
Char = F, Octal = 106, Decimal = 70
```

respectively.

Strange enough, none of these bindings work.

Comment: I'm itrigued by the output of the `what-key` function, because it sees really the H and F keys. However the <kbd>Ctrl<kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd><home></kbd> says there's an escape character. What does your H and F keys do?